# Max Tweets Searched For With 1 Request Twitter API

Tags: twitter

I'd like to know what is the maximum number of tweets I can query for in 15 minutes with App Auth. I know that I'm allowed 450 requests, but I'm not sure how many tweets I can query for with 1 request.
Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you go to [GET search/tweets](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/search/tweets), in the Paramters section you'll see an optional `count` that is set by default to 15. The maximum you can get is 100 tweets per query, so if you max out your limit you can get 45,000 tweets every 15 minutes.

Comment: Is that for EACH application I have registered? or for my entire account? So like if I had 10 api tokens could I get 450,000 in 15 minutes?

Comment: I haven't personally check this since I only have one app. However, when you check your limit it's tested against your `access_token`, so I would assume that's each `access_token` should have its own limit. I would check it at least once but you should be correct.